# Read a txt files accros an ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I try to develop an ajax input field can read a part of txt files.
But not sur I am in the good way.

The console read the file :

```
VM12083:1 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost//shop/Admin/ajax/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt?q=supplies".`
```

but the element is not displayed inside the input.

I use the tokeninput as library : http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

```
        $google_taxonomy_ajax = $this->link('ajax/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt');
//        $google_taxonomy_ajax = "https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt";

        $content .= '<div class="col-md-6">';
        $content .= HTML::inputField('google_taxonomy', $google_taxonomy_id . ' ' . $google_taxonomy_name, 'id="GoogleTaxonomy" class="token-input form-control"', null, null, null);
        $content .= '</div>';

          $output = <<<EOD
    <script>
    $('#categoriesName').append(
        '{$content}'
    );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#GoogleTaxonomy").tokenInput("{$google_taxonomy_ajax}" ,
            {
              tokenLimit: 1,
              resultsLimit: 5,
              onResult: function (results) {
                $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                  value.name = value.id + " " + value.name;
                });
                return results;
              }

            });
      });
    </script>
EOD;

        return $output;
```

Thank you

Comment: h`ttp is not valid

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, it's just an error with the copy / paste. No problem on that